# XML to Java Object

Tags: java, xml, object

I am trying to convert an XML file to a Java Object, now, I have read of JAXB, XStream, Sax and DOM, I'd like to convert this sort of type of xml:

```
<testxml testtype="converting" duration="100.00" status="successful" />
```

it might be as well as:

```
<testxml testype="converting" duration="100.00"> successful </textxml>
```

I wanted to know if there is anything out there (and possibly not 3rd party) that I can use, without declaring a template in DTD or in JAXB in XSD but Java (therefore I will declare a java class called testxml with all the relevant variable i.e. testtype, duration, status>

Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The class below using JAXB Annotations will do exactly what you need, no need to create an XSD or a template using Java 1.6+:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class TestXML {
  private String testtype;
  private double duration;
  private String status;

  public void setTesttype(String testtype) {
    this.testtype = testtype;
  }
  @XmlAttribute
  public String getTesttype() {
    return testtype;
  }
  public void setDuration(double duration) {
    this.duration = duration;
  }
  @XmlAttribute
  public double getDuration() {
    return duration;
  }
  public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
  }
  @XmlValue
  public String getStatus() {
    return status;
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    TestXML test = JAXB.unmarshal(new File("test.xml"), TestXML.class);

    System.out.println("testtype = " + test.getTesttype());
    System.out.println("duration = " + test.getDuration());
    System.out.println("status = " + test.getStatus());
  }
}
```

Using this as `test.xml`:

```
<testxml testtype="converting" duration="100.00"> successful </testxml>
```

Comment: WOW! thanks! and I suppose I will need to use the Unmarshall method right? thanks again!

Comment: Yes, the `main()` method is using the `JAXB.unmarshal()` method.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this pretty simply by using java.xml.bind.annotations on a Java class and JAXB.Unmarshal

JAXB is part of the JRE in java 1.6+

Comment: Nope-- just Unmarshal an annotated class with an InputStream that delivers the XML and you will get a populated Java object.  Unfortunately the docs make it sound much more complex then that.

Comment: Thanks! you and bamana gave me a great answer.. I should give you both the best answer! :( can only choose one though :( thanks a lot antlesoft!

Answer (score 1):

Try XStream/XPP3. That's good stuff. Takes a couple of hours to figure out. Does all the magic for you.

Comment: hmmm I really don't want to use 3rd party

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use XStream @ http://x-stream.github.io/ It's really easy to use and still offers enough features in case you need them. Unfortunately it looks like the project is not actively maintained anymore, but I haven't seen an alternative so far that suits my needs as well. I'd say it's worth spending a bit of time to check it out ;-)

edit: when you can use Java 6, I completely agree the other answers are preferable!